How to Query and update large data sets over several different SQL servers and DBs?
I need to know how to Query and update large data sets over several different SQL servers and DBs? Procedure in steps or any material to go through will be appreciated
Thanks in Advance
This is a requirment in some JDs of IT Support roles and I want to understand how this can be done
